# How to associate each individual doctor with a unique time schedule

Tags: javascript, postgresql, vue.js, vuejs2

Have a doctors array in vuex store pulling from postgres database that creates unique doctors that need to have associated time schedule based on start and end time. I don't know how to associate unique doctors with a generated unique dynamic time schedule. (Time schedule is array that will change by loop based on start and end time).

```html
<template>
   <v-container>
     <navbar/>
     <v-divider></v-divider>
       <h1> Weekly Calendar </h1>
       <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-sheet
            tile
            height="54"
            class="d-flex"
        >
        <v-btn
          icon
          class="ma-2"
          @click="$refs.calendar.prev()"
        >
            <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-select
          v-model="doctors"
          :items="doctors"
          item-text="firstName"
          dense
          outlined
          hide-details
          class="ma-2"
          label="doctors"
        ></v-select>
        <v-select
          v-model="mode"
          :items="modes"
          dense
          outlined
          hide-details
          label="event-overlap-mode"
          class="ma-2"
        ></v-select>
        <v-select
          v-model="timeslots"
          :items="times"
          item-text="startTime"
          dense
          outlined
          hide-details
          label="timeslots"
          class="ma-2"
        ></v-select>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn
          icon
          class="ma-2"
          @click="$refs.calendar.next()"
        >
          <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-sheet>
      <v-sheet>
        <v-calendar
            ref="calendar"
            :now="today"
            :value="today"
            :events="events"
            color="primary"
            type="week"
            :start="today"
          ></v-calendar>
      </v-sheet>
   </v-container>
</template>
<script>

import Navbar from '../components/Navbar.vue'
import doctorTimeService from '../services/DoctorTimeService.js'

export default {
    name: 'calendar',
    components: {
      Navbar
    },
    data() {
        return {
            mode: 'stack',
            modes: ['stack', 'column'],
            weekday: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            timeSlots: [],
            timeSlotByDoctor: [],
            today: new Date(),  
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getTimeSlots() {
          doctorTimeService.getAllTimeSlots().then(response => {
          this.$store.commit("SET_TIMESLOTS", response.data);
        });
      }
    },
    computed: {
      getTimeForDoc() {
      return null;
      }
      // loop over timeslots object to acces start time and end time
        // push first time into timeSlotByDoctor
        // each loop, increment minutes by 30
        // store start time hour and minute in object, and increment those values?
        // concat values back into time format, push into timeSlotByDoctor each iteration
    },
    created() {
        this.getTimeSlots();
        this.doctors = this.$store.state.doctors;
        this.timeSlots = this.$store.state.timeSlots;
        console.log('test', this.timeSlots);
        console.log(this.doctorNames);
    }
}
    
</script>

<template>
  <v-app>
   
      <div class="display-4 ma-4 d-flex justify-center">
        Doctors
      </div>
      <v-data-table
        :items="this.$store.state.doctors"
        :headers="headers"
        >
        <template v-slot:[`item.action`]="{item}">
          <v-btn @click="getItem(item)">Schedule Appointment</v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import doctorService from '../services/DoctorService.js';

export default {
  name: "doctor-list",
  computed: {
    headers() {
      return [
        {text: 'First Name', value: 'firstName'},
        {text: 'Last Name', value: 'lastName'},
        {text: 'Specialty', value: 'specialty'},
        {text: 'Suite', value: 'suiteNumber'},
        {text: 'Cost Per Hour', value: 'costPerHour'},
        {text: 'Schedule Appointment', value: 'action'}
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getDoctors() {
      doctorService.getAllDoctors().then(response => {
        this.$store.commit("SET_DOCTORS", response.data);
      });
    },
    getItem() {
      this.item = '';
      this.$router.push({name: 'doctor'})
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      doctors: [],  
      item: 'hello'
    }
  },
  created() {
      this.getDoctors();
  }
};
</script>
```

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Login from '../views/Login.vue'
import Logout from '../views/Logout.vue'
import Register from '../views/Register.vue'
import store from '../store/index'
import Calendar from '../components/Calendar.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

/**
 * The Vue Router is used to "direct" the browser to render a specific view component
 * inside of App.vue depending on the URL.
 *
 * It also is used to detect whether or not a route requires the user to have first authenticated.
 * If the user has not yet authenticated (and needs to) they are redirected to /login
 * If they have (or don't need to) they're allowed to go about their way.
 */

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: Login,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: false
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/logout",
      name: "logout",
      component: Logout,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: false
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/register",
      name: "register",
      component: Register,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: false
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/calendar",
      name: "calendar",
      component: Calendar,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
     {
      path: "/doctors/:id",
      name: "doctor",
      component: Calendar,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: false
      }
    },
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Determine if the route requires Authentication
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(x => x.meta.requiresAuth);

  // If it does and they are not logged in, send the user to "/login"
  if (requiresAuth && store.state.token === '') {
    next("/login");
  } else {
    // Else let them go to their next destination
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

I tried to get the Doctor ID by dynamic pages as it shows id here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html
but got stuck on how to actually get it.

I tried associating id with v-select button but got stuck on how to associate id with unique generated time schedule.

Comment: You're looking to solve a problem programmatically without solving it logically first, which is impossible. You need to at least figure out how to relate doctors to a time schedule logically before anyone can figure it out programatically.

Comment: Second comment form @yoduh. When you figure that out I'm guessing you will want to use [Range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) not arrays. In particular [range constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT).